# Возникла потребность в множественном наследовании при попытке сделать приложение гибким к изменениям

Tags: c#, unity3d

В игре на данный момент есть 4 класса юнитов, а именно PlayerSpaceBaseUnit, PlayerMiningUnit, PlayerBattleUnit и EnemyUnit. Хочется убрать дублирующийся код при помощи наследования и реализации интерфейсов, но возникла проблема с тем, что в интерфейсах можно описывать только статические поля, свойства, методы и индексаторы. Хотелось бы избежать дублирования не только методов, но и полей, чтобы расширение игры было проще. Обычного наследования не хватает, а множественное недоступно в c#. Как обычно выходят из подобных ситуаций? У меня пока что из идей только все поля заменить на автоматические свойства и решить проблему интерфейсами или оставить дубликаты. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше поступить в такой ситуации? На скриншоте представлена иерархия (нижние классы расписаны полностью для наглядности).

[image: Иерархия классов]

Comment: В с# нет множественного наследования только интересы

Comment: @ori Верно, я упомянул это в описании вопроса. Возможно я недостаточно конкретно выразился. Вопрос состоит в том, как правильно сделать аналогичную иерархию средствами с#?

Comment: Для сущностей, у которых будет схожее поведение, используются абстрактные классы. В них возможно использовать нестатические поля + реализовать базовую логику в общих методах

Comment: @АлександрПертенава А если класс должен унаследовать поля из множества классов? Практикуется ли создание отдельного класса (типа данных) для хранения полей и реализация интерфейсов для переопределения поведения?

Comment: Перед тем, как бросаться решать задачу наследованием, попробуйте подумать о решении композицией. Наследование - это уже последний рубеж :) Почитайте про поведенческие паттерны типа стратегии или посетителя или что подобное. Смысл в том, чтобы можно было создать юнит и уже во время выполнения программы добавлять ему способности ходить, стрелять, летать и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Множественное наследие это скорее баг, чем фича поскольку допускает несостыковки и противоречия, как наличие разных реализаций одинаковых методов у двух суперклассов и в c# его нет.

Ваша схема сама по себе не расширяема. Если я захочу сделать фичу захвата вражеских юнитов то это не возможно, поскольку контроль и управление почему-то вшито в сам класс юнита. Сделать 2ух врагов враждебных друг к другу тоже не получится по тем-же причинам. Кстате стрелочки на схеме не в ту сторону.

То что вы выдаете за `Unit` это вообще `Health` и он является полем `Unit`, типа такого:

```
public class Health
{
    public Action Died;
    public Action<float> Changed;
    
    public Health (float max)
    {
        Max = max;
        Amount = Max;
    }

    public float Amount { get; private set; }
    public float Max { get; private set; }
    public bool IsDead => Amount <= 0;

    public void TakeDamage (float damage)
    {
        SetAmouth(Amount-damage);
    }

    public void SetAmouth (float amouth)
    {
        float newAmount = Mathf.Clamp(amouth, 0, Max);
        if (Amount != newAmount)
        {
            Amount = newAmount;
            Changed?.Invoke(Amount);
            if (Amount <= 0)
                Died?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

`Unit` выглядит примерно так:

```
public class Unit : IDamagable
{
    public readonly Fraction Fraction; // enum
    public readonly Health Health;
    public readonly Select Select;
    public readonly Stats Stats;
    public readonly Attack Attack;
    public readonly Mining Mining;
    public readonly Movement Movement;
    ...
}
```

`Unit` не обязательно может быть способен двигаться или атаковать, потому что он например здание или башня которая атакует, но не двигается, поэтому `Attack` и `Movement` это абстрактные классы, которые могут быть `NonAttack` и `NonMovement`.

`PlayerUnit` и `EnemyUnit` вообще не должно существовать. Одни юниты управляются игроком, другие скриптом, но все это внешние команды для `Unit`, а не внутренние. `Unit` о существовании игрока и скрипта ии не должен знать, это не его ответственность.

Наследование от `Unit` оправдано только для расширения функионала, а не обвешивании других не связанных с ним. Например `HeroUnit` который имеет слоты инвенторя с предметами модифицирующие статы или добавлябщие эффекты, как герои из мобы и крипы.